# how can i find the angle of a reflecting line?

Tags: trigonometry

i am trying to make the game [pong](http://www.ponggame.org/) ( my math is really bad and i am working on it) and trying to do the bouncing ball part.

I am trying to calculate the out going(reflecting) angel of the ball after hitting the walls or pedals (the walls are always horizontal and the pedals are always vertical)

Here is an image to demonstrate it better :

[image: reflecting image]

here is what i tried so far:

m = (y2-y1) / (x2-x1)

angle = atan(-m);

How ever this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a reflecting line, $$B = A$$
For the game of pong though, the position of the paddle changes the angle.

Comment: B = A ? what you mean ?

Comment: @NetaMeta - if it hits' at $30^\circ$, it will bounce back at $180\circ - 30^\circ$. In your diagram, this means $A=B$.

Comment: So basically i should do 180 minus 30 ? by peddle changes the angle you mean their movement ? or the fact that if you hit the pedal not in middle the angle changes ?

Comment: @NetaMeta - I think both. Note that this is not a math issue, but rather how the game designers decide to make the game more interesting.

Comment: well, for now I'll skip those features for now as i think those are a alot more advanced.

Comment: i tried some angels with 180-angle didnt seem to work i check http://www.mathsisfun.com/angles.html, and if i try the angle 180-30 it works, but for other angles it doesnt add up